# How to set context to rxjs subscribe callback function?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I have a subscribe like this:

```js
this.test.subscribe(params => { 
  ...some code
});
```

If I pass a callback function instead of arrow function, the context is missing.

I want to bind the context to the subscribe function but I never see that.
is it possible to do without make something like

```js
that = this
```

Comment: What do you mean by `context`? Do you mean variables in the scope around `subscribe`? Or is it an Angular-specific notion?

Comment: Mean variables in the scope.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will attempt an answer but I'm still not quite sure what you mean.

When you write:

```
const v = 42;
observable.subscribe(x => {
  // here you have access to `v`
});
```

But when you write:

```
{
  const v = 42;
  observable.subscribe(f);
}

function f(x) {
  // here you do not have access to `v`
}
```

And that's how it should be. If you want `f` to see variables that are not in its declaration scope, then you must make them arguments and pass them appropriately. For instance:

```
{
  const v = 42;
  observable.subscribe(x => f(x, v));
}

function f(x, v) {
  // here you **do** have access to `v`
}
```

Or if you can define the callback in the context of the variable you want to capture:

```
{
  const v = 42;
  observable.subscribe(x => f(x));
  function f(x) {
    // here you **do** have access to `v` because it is in scope
  }
}
```

Does this answer your question? It has nothing to do with RxJS though, those are pure JavaScript (and programming languages) concepts.